# Drupal 8 - Get comments area on custom template

Tags: drupal-theming, drupal-8

I am trying to get the comment form with all comments on a custom template article page of drupal. I can get the whole content with `{{ page.content }}` or get the comments by using `{{ node.field_comments }}` and make a loop on it (assuming my field comment machine name is field_comments).

But does anyone know I to render the whole comments block with :

> - links to add a comment
> - comments
> - comment form

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the new and refined comment module. It's in the core so all you have to do is enable it. After that just make a comment type, add it to your article and display. That's pretty much it.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer !
I'm using a custom template page for articles because a have to split the content into different zone for designing it. So the fields are allready printed in page by using {{ node.field_xxxxx }} but I don't kown how to display the whole comment block with comments and comment form.

Answer (score 0):

In template files for a content type (eg node--article.html.twig), you have the 'content' variable available. I use this bit of Twig to render the whole comments block:-

```
{{ content.comment }}
```

Comment: How to get the comments field value on preview pages.{{content.field_commentfieldname}} working for node view but not for the node preview

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this too, but just for the next visitor, I got 2 out of 3 (I didn't want the form on my page)

```
 - links to add a comment -> {{ content.links }}
 - comments -> {{ content.comment_node_TYPE }}
```

To get the correct name for content.comment_node_TYPE, visit your Mange fields page for that content type and see what the comment field is called
e.g. my "Audio" content type names the field {{ content.comment_node_audio }}

Hope this helps someone in future